# VSDC, No audio while editing (Preview)

Tags: video-editor, audio, preview

There is no audio when I preview the clips while editing them. The project is on stereo, the latest update installed, "Don't Use Audio" is not selected in the clip's properties menu. Let me know a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should double-check:

- your speakers' volume (just in case)
- audio volume settings in VSDC[image] (see the image)